# How to use/sync data of controller in a directive?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

After some research, I'm not able to find the answer to my question.

I have a controller that fetch datas from a db, and I put some of the datas in a table (to use elsewhere).

```
Employees.getEmployees() // A service that return $http.get ...
        .success(function(data) {               
            $scope.employees = data;         
        });

$scope.salesData = [];
angular.forEach($scope.employees,function(employees){
    $scope.salesData.push(employees.totalSales);
});
```

I'd like to use this $scope.salesData in a directive, that creates a chart with D3JS.

```
angular.module('dirDonut', [])
.directive("linearChart", function($window) {
return{
    restrict: "EA",
    link: function(scope, el, attrs){

        // retrieve datas from the Controller
        var data=scope[attrs.chartData];

        // Here the code creates the chart ...
    }
  };
});
```

Then, in the HTML :

```
<div linear-chart chart-data="salesData"></div>
```

The problem is that the datas are not retrieved at all in the directive. I've got the error : Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.
If I hard code the values in the Controller it will work.

Any suggestions guys ? Sorry if I missed the answer in another post, I did not see any case like mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a synchronization problem. Your directive is compiled before your service returns the data, so `scope[attrs.charData]` is undefined.

What you need to do is wait for the data to become available:

```
app.directive("linearChart", function($window) {
    return{
        restrict: "EA",
        link: function(scope, el, attrs){
            scope.$watch(function() { 
                return scope[attrs.chartData]; 
            }, function(value) {
                var data = value;
                // Here the code creates the chart ...
            });    
        }
    };
});
```

[Working Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/8s6Stcvth59SScYC3qKv?p=preview)

You can learn more about the `$watch` function [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch).

Comment: Thanks Michael for the answer. But I have one more problem. I'm trying to create a set of data from $scope.employees. The angular.foreach() doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It doesn't work for the very same reason your directive didn't. You need to move that code into the `success` callback.